# No matching function for call to object of type 'const std::__1::packaged_task<void ()>', but `std::is_const` returns false

Tags: c++

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template<class Func, class... Args>
void submit(Func&& f, Args&&... args) {
  using returnType = typename std::result_of<Func(Args...)>::type;
  auto task1 = std::packaged_task<returnType()>(std::bind(std::forward<Func>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  std::cout << std::is_const<decltype(task1)>::value << " task1 const or not" << std::endl;

  auto tmp = [task2=std::move(task1)]() {
    std::cout << std::is_const<decltype(task2)>::value << " const or not" << std::endl;  // print 0, which means non-const
    // task2();  // uncomment this line, compilation will fail
  };
  tmp();

}

int main() {
  submit([&] {
    std::cout << "fooooooooo" << std::endl;
  });
  return 0;
}
```

I know the meaning of error; I know making lambda `mutable` will help and I test it, but I want to know where does the `const` come from. Note that `std::is_const` returns false, which makes me really confused.

EDIT:
Sorry forgot to mention the compiler. I was using clang-1000.10.44.2. The command is `clang++ -std=c++14 test.cpp -o test`

Comment: What's your compiler? On [GCC 8.2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LTEixm76QtpUUsbG) the printouts are as expected?

Comment: Same with GCC 9 @StoryTeller and Clang 8 . . .

Comment: @StoryTeller You are right, g++ 8.2 works fine. I was using clang-1000.10.44.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using Clang up to version 7.0. This behavior is documented by [bug report 38325](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38325). However, it also presents rationale why the behavior you see is not totally unreasonable. To quote Richard Smith from the bug report:

> Per [expr.prim.id.unqual]p2, the type of 'x' or 'y' within the lambda
>   is the type of a class member access expression naming the
>   corresponding capture. Those members are of type (non-const) int, but
>   the lambda's *this parameter is const-qualified

To explain it, recall that a lambda expression introduces a unique closure type. It's as if you wrote:

```
struct unique {
    decltype(task1) task2;
    void operator()() const { /* Your code */ }
};
unique const tmp = unique{std::move(tmp1)};
```

Now while `tmp` *is const*, the "type of the entity named" by the identifier `task2` is not const qualified (the member type has no cv-qualifications). So there you have it. Even though `task2` when used as a *postfix-expression* to the left of a function call operator preserves const qualifications, you may not see that when inspecting `decltype(task2)`. The workaround is to force `task2` to be treated as a regular expression, not subject to the special rules of `decltype` for id-expressions. You do that by adding parentheses:

```
std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<decltype((task2))>>::value
```

`decltype((task2))` will be appropriate to the type and value category of `(task2)`, which is `decltype(task1) const&`. `remove_reference_t` gives us `decltype(task1) const` and the predicate you check reports what you would expect.